# WooCommerce - Step filter not being picked up in Safari

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, safari

I have a site that I've built where products can only be added in batches of 6, I've added the below code, which works fine on every browser I've tested it on. But on Safari, it still allows products to be added singularly.

Is there any reason Safari wouldn't pick this code up? And anything I can do about it?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 6;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }
    $args['max_value']  = 6000000;  // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 6;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 6;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' ); // Variations

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 6000000;         // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 6;       // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I just can't see why this wouldn't work on certain browsers!

Comment: Can you provide the html output of the element ?

Comment: Ah so a bit more info! It works fine on the single product pages, but if you click "add to basket" from the archive pages, it adds a single product rather than 6.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the PHP, perhaps the html outputs is not correct

Comment: I figured out where it's wrong, I just can't figure out how to change it.

On the archive pages, the add to basket has this code: 
```
<a href="?add-to-cart=2297" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart " data-product_id="2297" data-product_sku="FR019" aria-label="Add “Christmas Kisses” to your basket" rel="nofollow">Add to basket</a>
```
but I can't figure out how to change the " data-quantity" to 6

Comment: Is this data-quantity set correctly in the other browsers ?